# How can I redefine verbatim to wrap lines (add break before or after spaces)?

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim, patching

Before continuing, I would like to inform readers that I know it is generally discouraged to reimplement functionality that packages already support.

- [Automatically wrap the text in verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121601/automatically-wrap-the-text-in-verbatim) has an accepted answer that does not address the question. The answer suggests using `listings`.
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14345/13552 is an answer to the aforementioned question that uses spaces as break points. This is useful for many applications, yet not all (e.g. HL7 messages, which do not use spaces).

## Packages that provide support for literal characters

- LaTeX2e's native `verbatim`
- `verbatim` a reimplementation of native LaTeX2e's `verbatim`
- `spverbatim` offshoot of verbatim that *almost* does what I want but only supports spaces and does not support custom environment names
- `fancyvrb`
- `listings` supports `breaklines=true` but has limitations with UTF-8 support and XeLaTeX and causes white text when used in combination with `tcolorbox` and `xelatex` (see [Why is text turning white (possible scope leak?) after page break and listings + tcolorbox + xelatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308672/why-is-text-turning-white-possible-scope-leak-after-page-break-and-listings))
- `minty` requires external scripts and does not support page breaks
- `verbments` requires external python scripts

## Goals

I hope to get an answer and gain some understanding here by doing it (partially) myself. Ultimately, I'd like to understand how line-breaking in verbatim text works.

- `verbatim` supports page breaks, but not line breaks (in programming terminology, line wrapping). I would like to utilize the `verbatim` package for code, but with line breaks.
- After reading through the `verbatim` and `spverbatim` documentation, I learned that **the definition of `\@xobeysp` is the target macro** for implementing breaks at spaces. For fun as well as a practical reason, I'd like to implement what the `spverbatim` package does to `verbatim` on my own. In the process, I'd like to understand what the `verbatim` documentation means when it says that I can use the `\every@verbatim` hook to modify the environments.
- Maybe I can use `\addto@hook<nameofhook>{commands to be added}` mentioned on page 4 of `verbatim` v. 2001/03/12?

Both packages are pretty well documented. Still, I need a little help to get me over the curve.

## My idea for `verbatim` environments that allow for line breaking

Maybe code could be injected at `\verbatim@processline` that breaks a line when the total length of the characters in a line has approximately reached `\textwidth`.

## My Idea for custom `verbatim` environments (an unsupported function of `spverbatim`) with breaks allowed at spaces

The `verbatim` mechanism for creating custom environments is explained in the  documentation on page 2 of version 2001/03/12.

### Attempt 1

Try to hack verbatim directly using `\addto@hook`.

```
\usepackage{verbatim}% http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim
\makeatother
\addto@hook\every@verbatim{\def\xobeysp{\mbox{}\space}}
\makeatletter
```

### Attempt 2

Try to imitate `spverbatim`.

Changing nonbreakable spaces to breakable spaces is made possible by redefining `\def\@xobeysp{\leavevmode\penalty10000\ }` to `\def\@xobeysp{\mbox{}\space}`

I know I am really close to creating my own environment with breakable spaces! 
`spverbatim.sty` is small enough that I can easily clone it and modify the name of the environment. However, it seems that I am still missing some step.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{myverbatim}
    [2016/05/11 v1.0 Verbatim with breakable spaces based on spverbatim]
\gdef\spverb{%
  \bgroup
  \let\spverb@ve=\verb@egroup
  \def\verb@egroup{\spverb@ve\egroup}%
  \def\@xobeysp{\mbox{}\space}%
  \verb
}
\begingroup
  \catcode`|=0
  \catcode`[=1
  \catcode`]=2
  \catcode`\{=12
  \catcode`\}=12
  \catcode`\\=12
  |gdef|spv@xverbatim#1\end{mycode}[#1|end[mycode]]
|endgroup
\newenvironment{mycode}{%
  \def\@xobeysp{\mbox{}\space}%
  \let\@xverbatim=\spv@xverbatim
  \verbatim
}{%
}
\endinput
```

Now I have a `mycode` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % typeset with xelatex
\usepackage{myverbatim} % custom package providing "mycode" env

\begin{mycode}
line-breakable literal characters { [ ] } $ &.
\end{mycode}
\end{document}
```

The parser is still reading passed the `\end{mycode}` and casuing an error.

Something like

> `! LaTeX Error: \begin{mycode} on input line 5 ended by \end{document}.`

What am I doing wrong here?

### Attempt 3

Clone the `verbatim.sty` code and replace the `\xobeysp` definition:

```
%\def\@xobeysp{\leavevmode\penalty\@M\ }
\def\@xobeysp{\mbox{}\space}
```

After replacing `\usepackage{verbatim}` with my new version, I can compile documents, but the lines are still not breaking at spaces.

## Limitation of `spverbatim`

This package does not allow me to create my own environments like in `verbatim`. I e-mailed the author about this at the time of writing this question.

## Create Custom Environments in `verbatim`

For the sake of completeness, here is how you would create a new environment:

```
\newenvironment{mycode}%
  {\endgraf\small\verbatim}%
  {\endverbatim}
```

## Pseudo-code from Attempt 1

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % typeset with xelatex
\usepackage{verbatim}
\makeatother
  \addto@hook\every@verbatim{\def\xobeysp{\mbox{}\space}}% similar to http://ctan.org/pkg/spverbatim
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\begin{mycode}
Here is some nice long code that should support breaks after each space, and not have the original penalty of 10000 like in the verbatim package such that each line will automatically be broken. A bonus would be to indent all wrapped lines by a given amount, but I realize that the logic involved here is somewhat more complex.
\end{mycode}
\end{document}
```

## Related Questions

- [Automatically wrap the text in verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121601/automatically-wrap-the-text-in-verbatim) just suggests `listings` and does not address issue in `verbatim`
- [Verbatim environment that can break too long lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14342/verbatim-environment-that-can-break-too-long-lines) this almost gets what I want, but not quite

Comment: I suspect the UTF-8 and verbatim will never be compatible, since LaTeX uses ASCII.  UTF-8 has to be translated into LaTeX equivalents first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but here it is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mycode}
 {\def\@xobeysp{\ }\verbatim\rightskip=0pt plus 6em\relax}
 {\endverbatim}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{mycode}
aaa { \ } aaa { \ } aaa { \ } aaa { \ } aaa { \ } aaa { \ } aaa { \ } aaa { \ } aaa { \ } aaa { \ } aaa { \ } aaa { \ } 
bbb { \ } bbb { \ } bbb { \ } bbb { \ } bbb { \ } bbb { \ } bbb { \ } bbb { \ } bbb { \ } bbb { \ } bbb { \ } bbb { \ } 
\end{mycode}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, that directly answers the question. I was hoping for more of an explanation for my understanding as well (e.g. why my modifications to `spverbatim` failed or why `\rightskip=0pt plus 6em\relax` works right after you call `\verbatim`). Then I can master this business of adjusting `verbatim` to meet my needs in the future. e.g. Suppose I wanted to make two different characters allow for line breaks? Say perhaps pipes `|`? Is that possible? or even all characters?

Comment: @macmadness86 Sorry, but your question is very long and it's quite difficult to understand what you really want.