# Word wrap 64 character hexadecimal strings in verbatim JSON

Tags: line-breaking, texlive, documentation, json

I'd like to document example requests/replies in our protocol per [How to write narrative documentation](http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=8175). We're using the texlive-latex-base on Ubuntu for our documentation, and I'm linting with `lacheck` and `chktex` - I've managed to fix all warnings.

From questions such as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324042/28176) I've managed to get runs of hex in my paragraphs flowing well, with the `seqsplit` package (might have to accept an extra dependency for it).

I need to document JSON with 32 byte hex encoded values. I've tried wrapping `\verb||` with `\seqsplit{}` and with `\begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}` without success. I've tried putting `\verb` only around the `{ "key": "` and `" }` parts, and using `\texttt` and `\seqsplit` on the inner part without success - the line still merrily flows right off the page. Ah, these are in a `\begin{tabular}{l l}...\end{tabular}` in `\item`s of a `\begin{description}...\end{description}` block if relevant.

How can I get these `\verbatim` long lines to wrap? The [common answer appears to be](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121601/28176) `\lstlisting`, but it has not worked for me, and additionally causes the linter to complain about `"`s from the JSON.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\newcommand{\hex}[1]{\texttt{0x#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{Examples}

Long 1: \hex{\seqsplit{d3c67ea2cafd4b3490a6dd0c61c1c3255be4ce2347aa0b123ef95acf4d89085a}}. Long 2: \hex{\seqsplit{9187043bcace4747eccf865281848e871724ac944631e95ccb4afa87c2a42774}}.\\

\begin{description}
    \item [From $\rightarrow$ To] Get long string $\rightarrow$ \texttt{\seqsplit{9187043bcace4747eccf865281848e871724ac944631e95ccb4afa87c2a42774}}
    \item [From $\rightarrow$ To] \begin{tabular}{l l}
        \texttt{POST} & \texttt{/api/endpoint} \\
        Request & \verb|{ "long1": "9187043bcace4747eccf865281848e871724ac944631e95ccb4afa87c2a42774" }| \\
        Response & \verb|{ "long2": "cd18978a5da7a0f7673e9185e8018aff3de003bbc4f3cfd133be27466173f66d" }| \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of my prior attempts succeeded once I realized it was in a `\begin{tabular}{l l}...\end{tabular}` - particularly the `l` in `tabular` prevents wrapping. `\seqsplit` worked once I changed the second tabular `l` to `p{9cm}` and the innermost lines to:

```
        Request & \verb|{ "long1": "|\texttt{\seqsplit{9187043bcace4747eccf865281848e871724ac944631e95ccb4afa87c2a42774}}\verb|" }| \\
        Response & \verb|{ "long2": "|\texttt{\seqsplit{cd18978a5da7a0f7673e9185e8018aff3de003bbc4f3cfd133be27466173f66d}}\verb|" }| \\
```