# How do you automatically wrap text in the \verb||-like environment -- that is, in-line, and without requiring a line break before and after?

Tags: listings, verbatim

This is my first question on any StackExchange site, so please bear with me.

I am writing code for a paragraph of normal English with little bits of code spliced in. Initially I wrote something like:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod \verb|\tikzset{help lines/.style = gray, very thin}| tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.`

However, in the output of that code, the phrase "`\tikzset{help lines/.style = gray, very thin}`" tended to poke out of the margins. Therefore, I was relieved to find Gonzalo Medina's solution to *that* problem at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121618/277990. However, his solution causes a different problem, which is what my question is about. Namely, his solution requires the phrase "`\tikzset{help lines/.style = gray, very thin}`" to appear on its own line, whereas I want it to appear "in-line." (The difference I'm talking about is similar to that between display-style math and text-style math.)

Please let me know whether I've explained my question clearly. I haven't tried many solutions, because I'm still new to LaTeX so I wouldn't know where to begin. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: What happens if you replace `\verb|\tikzset{help lines/.style = gray, very thin}|` with `{\ttfamily\string\tikzset\{help lines/.style = gray, very thin\}}`?

Comment: Perhaps the following can work. Set `listings` package: `\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, breaklines=true}` and use `\lstinline|<code here>|`  to put a content in verbatim with line breaks.

Comment: @Celdor, that works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a verb which uses normal stretchy, breakable, space

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod \verb|\tikzset{help lines/.style = gray, very thin}| tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
\verb|\tikzset{help lines/.style = gray, very thin}| tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

{
\makeatletter
\let\@xobeysp\space
\makeatother

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod \verb|\tikzset{help lines/.style = gray, very thin}| tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
\verb|\tikzset{help lines/.style = gray, very thin}| tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

}
\end{document}
```